# How to make "can you tell me guys" with respect?

Tags: british-english, writing, parsing

I am writing mail for my seniors. I want to ask something like, `Can you tell me guys which port I have to use?` How to make this word as polite?

Comment: Just write "Please can you tell me which port I have to use." By the way are you talking about a computer port, a cargo port or a type of fortified wine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word order with "me guys" is not correct. "Guys" should appear straight after "you", in informal speech. However, just leave out "guys" entirely in formal speech, and add "please" to make it polite:

> Can you please tell me which port I should use?

I am also changing "have to" to "should", because this indicates that you aren't being forced to use a particular port. This point is more a matter of interpretation that grammar. Using the word "should" indicates that you have free will, are responsible and are in control of your actions. Thus, you can decide for yourself which port to use, but are merely asking for advice on which decision is the best one.

Comment: "me guys" is fine.  It's another version of "Guys!  Can you tell me which ..."  (However "guys" is not appropriate in formal speech or writing).

Comment: Martin, "you guys" is the subject of the sentence, and I see no reason why it should be split up, with words put in between.

Comment: That's a different construction.  I read the original sentence as having "You" as the subject with "guys" as an interjection.

Comment: I've also noticed that the question is tagged "british-english", and to me, "guys" is an Americanism.  (That may not be true for younger BrE speakers - I'm 60).

Comment: Ok, well if it were an interjection, it would need commas: "Can you tell me, guys, which port I have to use?"

Comment: I don't understand why you think "should" is better than "have to" here.  What is the difference between "tell me what I have to do [to make this work]" and "tell me what I should do [if I want this to work]"?

Comment: @Juhasz I just don't like the notion that people are forced to do something. Also, there could be more than one way to do it, but "have to" covers up that fact.

Comment: @Juhasz my thoughts on that word usage derive from my studies of mathematics, where I disliked it when a learner asked, for example, "Do I have to take x across?" My immediate reaction was, "Why should anybody force you to do that? You should make that decision for yourself."

Comment: OK.  Seems like we would need to know the exact context to know whether the use of a specific port is a requirement.  If the context is "I want to send an HTTP request to your server.  Which port should I use?" there really is no choice.  Your choice is use 80 or use something else which won't work.

Comment: Or *Can you guys tell me. . .?*